# How can i set http header on exception?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

i want to add a custom http header on error 500 pages and i would like to do it in the controller - i just can't figure it out.

This is what i have tried:

```
public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
    {
        var statusCode = ((HttpException) filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode();
        if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Custom-Key", "error");
        }
    }
}
```

Howevere, it doesn't add the header, so something must be wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you missed to handle the exception. I strongly recommend you to do this within a try catch block (if you do so you will not be able catch this exception in `OnException` method).

But just to answer you question, you need to tell the context that this Exception is Handled. You need the following line :

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
```

**Alltogether :**

```
public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
    {
        var statusCode = ((HttpException)filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode();
        if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Custom-Key", "error");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot rustem!